# Conditional formatting with custom formula

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I cannot seem to make my conditional formatting work with a custom formula. The long and short of it is that the formatting is based on some `VLOOKUP`s. I've tested the formula in a normal cell and it outputs 1 as expected.

`=IF(REGEXMATCH(VLOOKUP(C5,CL!C2:H99,5,FALSE), VLOOKUP(B5,CL!J3:K110,2,FALSE)), 1, 0)`

I'm basically testing to see whether a certain tag is included in a cell that contains a comma separated list of tags.

The documentation seems to suggest that I need to enter the formula into the box with quotation marks around it (`""`). I've tried all variations I believe.

I've also tried removing the `IF` statement, as `REGEXMATCH` outputs `true` or `false`.

Any clue why this isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when attempting conditional formatting to reference another sheet you need to wrap it into `INDIRECT` - that's where Google documentation failed. try:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(VLOOKUP(C5, INDIRECT("CL!C2:H99"), 5, 0), 
               VLOOKUP(B5, INDIRECT("CL!J3:K110"), 2, 0)), 1)
```